# Assign value to data based on more than two conditions and on other data

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
> df
   name time count
1     A   10     9
2     A   12    17
3     A   24    19
4     A    3    15
5     A   29    11
6     B   31    14
7     B    7     7
8     B   30    18
9     C   29    13
10    C   12    12
11    C    3    16
12    C    4     6
```

and for each name group (A, B, C) I would need to assign a category following the rules below:

- if time<= 10 then category = 1
- if 10 <time<= 20 then category = 2
- if 20 <time<= 30 then category = 3
- if time> 30 then category = 4

to have a data frame that looks like this:

```
> df_final
   name time count category
1     A   10     9        1
2     A   12    17        2
3     A   24    19        3
4     A    3    15        1
5     A   29    11        3
6     B   31    14        4
7     B    7     7        1
8     B   30    18        3
9     C   29    13        3
10    C   12    12        2
11    C    3    16        1
12    C    4     6        1
```

after that I would need to sum the value in count based on their category. The ultimate data frame should loo like this:

```
> df_ultimate
   name count category
1     A    24        1
2     A    17        2
3     A    30        3
4     A    NA        4
5     B     7        1
6     B    NA        2
7     B    18        3
8     B    14        4
9     C    22        1
10    C    12        2
11    C    13        3
12    C    NA        4
```

I have tried to play around with summarise and group_by but without much success.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Rather than posting your data like that, it is more useful to post the output of e.g. `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `cut` + `complete`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(name, category = cut(time, breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 20, 30, Inf), labels = 1:4)) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count)) %>% 
  complete(category)

#  # Groups:   name [3]
#    name  category count
#  1 A     1           24
#  2 A     2           17
#  3 A     3           30
#  4 A     4           NA
#  5 B     1            7
#  6 B     2           NA
#  7 B     3           18
#  8 B     4           14
#  9 C     1           22
# 10 C     2           12
# 11 C     3           13
# 12 C     4           NA
```